# c# regex.ismatch using a variable

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code which works fine but i need to replace the site address with a variable...

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;  // Get the URL

bool match = Regex.IsMatch(url, @"(^|\s)http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/index.aspx(\s|$)");
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work, any ideas???

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;  // Get the URL
string myurl = "http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/index.aspx";

bool match = Regex.IsMatch(url, @"(^|\s)"+myurl+"(\s|$)");
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it just not matching when you pass it as a variable or is it throwing an exception?

Comment: the error was near \s, i managed to fix it by escaping: \\s

Comment: @Scott see Mark Byers answer then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing a `@`:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(url, @"(^|\s)" + myurl + @"(\s|$)");
```

The reason that you need the extra `@` is because the `@` applies only to the string literal immediately following it. It does not apply to the entire rest of the line.

You should also consider [escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) your URL:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(url, @"(^|\s)" + Regex.Escape(myurl) + @"(\s|$)");
```